# how to find the id of each map task?

Tags: mapreduce, mapper, reducers

I want to get the id of each mapper and reducer task because I want to tag the output of these mappers and reducers according to the mapper and reducer id. How can I retrieve the ids of each?

Thanks

Comment: Not my domain, so this might be obvious, but it seems to me that some indication of language or platform in the tags may help!

Answer (score 3):

You can print taskId in map, setup etc. functions by utilizing following code.

```
context.getTaskAttemptID().getTaskID();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext::getTaskAttemptID().